# RadGrid in does not go in editmode

Tags: asp.net, .net, radgrid

I have RadGrid on an ascx control with one ImageButton in TemplateColumn. ImageButton has CommandName=”Edit”.
So when I click the image button it sets the grid in Edit mode. I have some code on ItemDataBound event of grid that works if  e.Item.IsInEditMode is true.

The whole thing works on local but when I deploy the code on TEST environment then it doesn’t work. After putting some log statements I found out that on this environment when user clicks Imagebutton it doesn’t set the grid in Edit mode and e.Item.IsInEditMode is never true.

I have 2 different Test environments, this functionality works on one the Test environment but not on another one. Both the servers have same windows update and IIS configuration.

any idea what else can cause this problem?

additional Info: I am using SessionPageStatePersister for view state

Answer (score 0):

i just figured this one out. On one of the server my web.config had wrong domain name in httpCookies element. It was different than actual domain name. That's why view state was not working.